# Error while displaying qgis project via qgis2leaf plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.10

couldn't see the map on the browser while using QGIS2LEAF Plugin in QGIS 2.10 Pisa. It gives error on web page saying:

> error at line 8: L is undefined.

Please let me know if anyone knows the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the reference to the Leaflet mapping library is incorrect or missing.  You must either have a valid local copy with a correct path (in the head or after the body of the HTML but before your map script) or reference the CDN.  Read the [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html) documentation on how to do it.

---

QGIS2LEAF is no longer under development so you may have better luck with QGIS2WEB anyway, which supersedes it.